# Python decorator won't run in unit test

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-decorators

I had the bright idea to make a decorator I could append to my unit tests to assert expected changes happened, which I just can't get to work.  To simplify things I now have a basic decorator created as a test, which still fails to run the wrapped inner method.  I'm trying to figure out why it won't run.  This is all in a class extending unittest.TestCase

```
def work_please(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception('in work please decorator')
    return wrapped

@work_please  
def test_01_client_init(self):
    self._mock_start_server.assert_called()
```

I run this and the test pass, when they should fail due to the raised exception.

This is one of a few test cases, in every case no matter what type of decorator I try (the original being parameterized) the original decorator method(s) run but the inner most function the decorator returns never gets called.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. which version of python or you using? Can you also include a minimal example of the class you are using for testing, the command you are running to run the tests, and the output you are getting?